# Is there a possible way to create dynamic periodic tasks in Celery?

Tags: python, celery, periodic-task

I would like to add and remove periodic tasks from the celery scheduler, however I do not find an easy way to do that. Is it possible?

I found the next question, but I wonder if there is an alternative which does not use Django.
[How to dynamically add / remove periodic tasks to Celery (celerybeat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194975/how-to-dynamically-add-remove-periodic-tasks-to-celery-celerybeat)

Comment: You could also leverage Tornado PeriodicCallbacks to run tasks at a given interval, and clear the callback whenever you need. Why do you "need" Celery?

Comment: Well, it's a big project that uses celery tasks. I need to run some of those tasks at a certain point in time which is calculated based on events. Those events also could cancel the execution of those tasks. Something like "if event X happens, execute task Y in T time from now. However, if Z event happens before T, cancel task Y execution".

Comment: I see, then I think you should stay with celery for that.

Answer (score 0):

For removing the tasks from celery scheduler you can use like

```
from celery.task.control import discard_all
discard_all()
```

And you can see a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400305/python-celery-how-to-append-a-task-to-an-old-chain) on how to append tasks to a scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. There is a package [django-celery-beat](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat) that provides `PeriodicTask` database model. It can be used to dynamically add/remove/update/pause periodic tasks.

Some time ago, I needed dynamic periodic tasks, and I wrote an example project, which is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/saasitive/dynamically-update-periodic-tasks), and wrote an article about [dynamic periodic tasks in Celery and Django](https://saasitive.com/tutorial/dynamically-update-periodic-tasks-celery/).